# AFrame broken on iPhone?

Tags: aframe, google-cardboard

Does AFrame support Cardboard for iPhone?

The [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/#what-is-a-frame) lists Cardboard in the list of supported platforms. However, when I try on my iPhone (for example the [helloworld demo](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/)), I just see a screen saying "Insert phone into Cardboard holder".

Steps to reproduce:

- Grab iPhone, start Safari web browser
- Navigate to https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/
- press the "goggles" icon on the bottom right

Expected:

The view splits, showing an image for each eye

Actual:

Screen shows "Insert phone into Cardboard holder". Inserting the phone into a Cardboard holder does nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? Or does AFrame not work for this particular configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rotating the phone with screen lock off.

Comment: OMG that was it! Now if only we could change the message so it tells the user that!